# playing mp3 from a folder which has .htaccess restriction for download

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, playback

I have been trying to make a music streaming website.

I store all the mp3 in www.abc.com/audio folder .

This folder has .htaccess restriction so that none can download any file.

After so much of searching I am unable to find how to play mp3 from this folder using php from this folder.

The PHP code for the play file is filename: play.php

```
<?php
//print_r($_GET);
include_once('./functions.php');

$path=getPathFromHash($_GET['value']);   //get path from hash_value ex. www.abc.com/audio/1.mp3
echo $track = getFileNameFromHash($_GET['value']);  //get file name ex. 1.mp3

if (file_exists($track)) {
header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg");
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($track));
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=' . $track);
header('X-Pad: avoid browser bug');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
readfile($track);
exit;
} else {
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 404 Not Found', true, 404);
    echo "no file";
}


?>
<audio src="<?php echo $path?>" autoplay loop controls></audio>
```

my .htaccess file in audio folder is

```
<FilesMatch ".(ogg|mp3)$">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

But after all this, the song is not playing :(
What changes should I make so that song starts to play?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is the above file located? What is the result you get from the script at the moment?

Comment: www.abc.com/play.php and the folder is at www.abc.com/audio

At present, the html5 audio is showing on the page but song is not played by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems that I can see:

1)

```
echo $track = getFileNameFromHash($_GET['value']);
```

Remove the `echo` from this line. This will cause the file name to be output and will at least corrupt the file data, it will probably prevent the headers from being set correctly as well.

2)

You probably need to tell PHP that the files are in the `audio/` directory. You say that `getFileNameFromHash()` returns `ex. 1.mp3` - well PHP will look for 1.mp3 in the current working directory, which according to your comment above will be the webroot.

Try changing the line mentioned above to

```
$track = 'audio/' . getFileNameFromHash($_GET['value']);
```

...which will also mean you should change the `Content-Disposition` line to:

```
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . basename($track) . '"');
```

---

All of this assumes that `$path` contains a sensible value. It should be `/play.php?value=<hash value expected by your functions>`

Comment: the html5 audio is not showing now and if I comment the the line
    readfile($track);
it is showing the html5 audio but song is not playing

Comment: @RahulKumar Please show some actual sample values returned by the `getPathFromHash()` and `getFileNameFromHash()` functions, as well as the "hash" value you supplied to get those values.

Comment: getPathFromHash() - ./audio/Abhi na jao chhod kar.mp3

    getFileNameFromHash() - /audio/Abhi na jao chhod kar.mp3

   hash value : d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e

hash value and respective filepath is stored in a db table and the function is just retrieving path from the hash value and the track is extracted from  path using the explode function.

Comment: @RahulKumar The problem you have here is that you cannot get the value of `$path` without passing a value in the first place, so you have a circular reference. You need to separate the code that produces the HTML from the code that sends the file to the browser.

Comment: @RahulKumar Try running this code and you'll see what I mean: http://pastebin.com/GHaVx3tg

Comment: �x�ŗ�MӸ�[q\���3���_�� ��s���u�?� c* [�C�o�x�տJ���H�ҲM�߭9&Fz�P�Xo�Y� #?�j�˰��b�FS���u�ǵEX�TU)�.fuѲ��v�=��\���!�°>&��P����m2ͥ�f��,��g'=�Ω Y���gqݞ��ʗ?Oʼ��5(���ק[� #JT "��du�=���d����Kc������^�5�3u-~�M�H��E1�va*2��S��=��1�Cdb�T����"F�a}~騵��T�g��p�ƨѡr���L�o'�8��a���Z4rNE���K �;zr2~� v8���G��V�/"��. �D7�N��zf��jQX�;�`"n��Y��Y��bɭ��5��fݸg��鎪֥��c�XM��������)�c�x�I��á��ĳy�XX9�#M�`�OК_�IlRU�O>6s"��

this is the some top lines of output I am getting...
i have included the line 

`header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");`

but the result is same

Comment: @RahulKumar Well that's the mp3 file - can you show your current code?

Comment: the code is exactly same as yours but I have include the above line before `readfile` function

[link]http://pastebin.com/WSWn5DaP

Comment: @RahulKumar What address did you put in the address bar?

Comment: the page is being redirected from ajax... the value would be www.abc.com/play.php?value=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  and then you are giving the same souce as the src in audio tag... isn't it going to be an infinitive loop???